# Proof clarification for Gumbel distribution, Billingsley proof

Tags: measure-theory, probability-distributions

I'm reading Billingsley's Probability and measure. I'm reading about extremal distributions, and I'm at where he is proving that Gumbel is one of the extremal distributions.

I'm having a hard time understanding the proof and I'll appreciate it if someone helps me figure out the proof. The text highlighted in yellow is what i don't understand (it is quite half of the proof). Thank you in advance.
[image]

[image]

Comment: The first one follows from the fact that $F(x)\in[0,1]$ and hence $F^k(x)\geq F^{k+1}(x)$ for all $k$, i.e. the sequence $F^k(x)$ is non-increasing. Therefore if equation 14.20 holds we have that $F(x+d_k)\geq F(x+d_{k+1})$ and since distribution functions are non-decreasing, we must have $x+d_k\geq x+d_{k+1}$, i.e. $d_k\geq d_{k+1}$.